# Clickable DIV or A tag?

Tags: html, clickable

I have a box on my homepage marked up with the following code:

```
<div class="panel radius">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit curabitur elit libero, porta condimentum lobortis laoreet, faucibus eget.</p>
</div>
```

I want to make the whole box clickable. Would it be better to change the DIV to an A tag or use jQuery to make the DIV clickable? Just looking for the best solution.

Comment: Use jquery to make it clickable.

Comment: Clickable to go to another place or what for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".panel radius").click(function(){
            window.location = URL; 
        });
    });
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qUyp2/84/)**